# Select from EXTERNAL via LOCATION statement

Tags: azure, select, azure-data-lake, u-sql

I would like to write query

```
@result =
  SELECT * //Id, Test
  FROM EXTERNAL MyAzureSQLDBDataSource LOCATION "dbo.test"
  WHERE Test NOT LIKE "_C";
```

But I got an error:

> C# error CS0103: The name 'Test' does not exist in the current
>   context.

If I'm running query without WHERE statements, everything works well. The same problem is in SELECT, I get an error if I use column names in query  instead of *

Any idea why I cannot use location and where statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the schema definition of the dbo.test table?

I assume that the dbo.test table in the Azure SQLDB either does not provide the column Test or it is spelled in a different case (note that U-SQL is - unlike T-SQL - case-sensitive).

Comment: The schema is correct. If I run query via execute statement everything works fine.

Comment: The EXECUTE statement ships a T-SQL statement over. I assume that your database is case-insensitive so it may not care about the casing. But U-SQL is case-sensitive, so it may get the table meta-data in a different casing. What is the result of

`@result =
  SELECT * FROM EXTERNAL MyAzureSQLDBDataSource LOCATION "dbo.test" ORDER BY "one" FETCH 1;
  OUTPUT @result TO "\output\test.csv" USING Outputters.Csv(outputHeader:true);` ?

Comment: Thanks, that's my case. You right, in DB are columns defined with lowercase.

Comment: Glad we found the issue :)